# Using twimlets in a Twilio Play verb

Tags: twilio

I thought it I could specify any URL - including the twimlets used in conference calls - in the Play verb of a TwiML file. However, the following does not work...

http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.classical#&Message=please%20wait

... and neither does the twimlet when I strip away the arguments...

http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.classical

Does the Play noun work differently?

```
<Response>
    <Say>Please wait while I work on your request</Say>
    <Play>http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.classical&amp;amp;Message=please%20wait</Play>
</Response>
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed this until today. Sorry Greg!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) only supports audio files and the hold music Twimlet is generating TwiML of it's own with a series of `<Play>` verbs that contain actual audio URLs.

What you would want to do is [`<Redirect>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect) to that URL which would start the hold music. Let me know if that works for you!